# C++ oveloaded operator+ and <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
struct Complex
{
    int real;
    int imaginary;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Complex& temp)
{
    output << temp.real << " + " << temp.imaginary << 'i' << endl;
    return output;
}
Complex& operator+(Complex& c1, Complex& c2)
{
    Complex ans;
    ans.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    ans.imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
    return ans;
}



int main()
{
    Complex temp;
    cin >> temp;
    Complex temp2;
    cin >> temp2;
    Complex ans;
    ans = temp + temp2;
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
  1 2
  1 2
```

Output

```
2 + 4i
-858993460 + -858993460i
```

I'm new to C++ and i haved coded some program
I'm so confused about the result of this program. Please explan what wrong with my knowledge about C++. Thanks for any helps

Comment: Returning a local variable in a function with return value of reference typ e is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Your `operator+` returns a reference to a local variable. The variable goes out of scope when the function returns, and the reference becomes dangling before it could be used. Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. Return by value instead.

Comment: Question is not clear, as we don't know what's your current knowledge. Statically analyzing the code: As mentioned by @IgorTandetnik, you return a reference to a function-local object, which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: How does this even compile?  You define `ostream& operator<<` but `cin >> temp;` needs a `istream& operator>>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, now i understand what wrong :)

Comment: I just forget copy this function @NathanOliver. Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a local variable by reference. Try this instead:

```
Complex operator+(Complex& c1, Complex& c2)
{
    Complex ans;
    ans.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    ans.imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
    return ans;
}
```

Notice the abscence of the & after Complex in the function declaration. You can't return a local variable by reference, the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting some garbage value after the actual answer. The reason is here:

```
Complex& operator+(Complex& c1, Complex& c2)
{
    Complex ans;
    ans.real = c1.real + c2.real;
    ans.imaginary = c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary;
    return ans;
}
```

The function return type is `Complex&`, your `ans` is just `Complex` and you just return that. If you change your return type to `Complex`, everything will be consistent. With `Complex&` you are basically trying to return a reference to a variable that will not be found in the scope.

See this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) for better understanding. Hope this solves your issue.